# Updating data to a new column

Tags: mysql

So similar questions have been asked but none include an answer for many rows.
Say I have an existing table with data filled up and I just added a new column.
Now I want to add data to existing rows for that new column, but I don't want to do it 1 by 1, I want for example to add the name 'john' to each row in the new column. How do I do that?

Comment: Add `default 'john'` after the datatype when adding the new column.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using SQL. Use the update command.

```
UPDATE tablename SET new_column = "John"
```

you can add condition too like

```
UPDATE tablename SET new_column = "John" WHERE last_name = "Smith"
```

Comment: I know how to do the update command, i was wondering if there was a way to do it with many rows simultaneously

Comment: The first command will change new_column in every row to "John". 

The second one will change all the rows where the last name is Smith.

Comment: @Tousa1 - Yes, they do all rows "simultaneously".  (Under the covers, it is done one by one, but it is "simultaneous" from the programmer's point of view.)  It will be quite efficient.